# Why do font awesome icons overlap with border?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

Why do the icons  overlap the border?
I know that `padding` will solve the problem, but I want to know the reason for the overlapping.

```css
i {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px red solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<i class="fab fa-500px fa-5x"></i>
<!--icon1-->
<i class="fab fa-accusoft fa-5x"></i>
<!--icon2-->
```

Comment: The same reason that any symbol in any font would overlap the border: it's too big to fit inside.

Comment: Does adding fa-fw to each icon's class help at all?

Comment: Adding `overflow: hidden;` will clip the glyphs at the element border, if that's what you want.

Comment: It looks like the symbols overlap mainly because `border-radius` reduces the volume of the `<i>` elements; remove the radius to see what I mean. Agreed, some `padding` will probably suffice.

Comment: fa-fw will not solve the problem .
i understood now the reason . thanks all  :)

Answer (score 0):

Font awesome draw an SVG icon, so in your case icon is not optimised for border-radius CSS property.

Unfortunately, you need to customise CSS for each.

see example below.

```css
.fa-500px {
   margin: 10px;
}

.fa-accusoft {
    margin: 0;
}

div {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px red solid;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
    <i class="fab fa-500px fa-5x"></i>
</div>
<!--icon1-->
<br />
<div>
    <i class="fab fa-accusoft fa-5x"></i>
</div>
```